# Column does not exits in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE LuxRoom
(
 roomID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT roomID_ref_room REFERENCES Room(roomID),
 peopleNumber INT NOT NULL,
 additionalService TEXT
)
```

But when I do insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO LuxRoom(roomID, peopleNumber, additionalService) VALUES(1, 2, "Extra food, a cab");
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "Extra food, a cab" does not exist
```

What is the problem?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Single quotes delimit a string constant or a date/time constant.
>
> Double quotes delimit identifiers for e.g. table names or column
>   names. This is generally only necessary when your identifier doesn't
>   fit the rules for simple identifiers.

replace double quotes with single quote

```
INSERT INTO LuxRoom (roomID, peopleNumber, additionalService) 
VALUES (1, 2, 'Extra food, a cab');
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is "picky" in terms of SQL syntax and makes a difference between ' and ".  " indicates, that it's an object, ' it's a string. So your query should look like

```
INSERT INTO LuxRoom(roomID, peopleNumber, additionalService) 
VALUES(1, 2, 'Extra food, a cab');
```

This is different to e.g. behaviour on MySQL, but the standard way.

Comment: This is not "*picky*" this is how the SQL standard has been defined (nearly 30 years ago). And it's not "more" standard. It's "the standard". MySQL simply chose to ignore that already existing standard. And nearly all other DBMS (Oracle, DB2, Firebird, ....) also behave that way.

Comment: picky was meant compared to behaviour of MySQL -- personal I really think enforcing this is a good idea.